# Как сделать выпадающее меню в несколько столбцов? WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу сделать меню в несколько столбцов. В дропдауне много пунктов, поэтому нужно разделить их на несколько столбиков. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Можете взять меню отсюда:
https://www.cssscript.com/creating-a-simple-mega-menu-with-pure-html-css/

Демо:
https://www.cssscript.com/demo/creating-a-simple-mega-menu-with-pure-html-css/#

```css
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");

/* mini reset */
.nav,
.nav a,
.nav ul,
.nav li,
.nav div,
.nav form,
.nav input {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav li {
  list-style: none;
}

/* menu container */
.nav,
input {
  font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.nav {
    cursor: default;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 500;
}

/* menu list */
.nav > li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

/* menu links */
.nav > li > a {
  background: #372f2b;
  border-left: 1px solid #4b4441;
  border-right: 1px solid #312a27;
  display: block;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 54px;
  line-height: 54px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  z-index: 510;
}
.nav > li:hover > a {
  background: #4b4441;
}
.nav > li:first-child > a {
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* search form */
.nav > li.nav-search > form {
  border-left: 1px solid #4b4441;
  height: 54px;
  position: relative;
  width: inherit;
  z-index: 510;
}
.nav > li.nav-search input[type="text"] {
  background: #372f2b;
  color: #999;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: left;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease 1s;
  transition: all .3s ease 1s;
  width: 1px;
}
.nav > li.nav-search input[type="text"]:focus {
  color: #fcfcfc;
}
.nav > li.nav-search input[type="text"]:focus,
.nav > li.nav-search:hover input[type="text"] {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .1s;
  transition: all .3s ease .1s;
  width: 110px;
}
.nav > li.nav-search input[type="submit"] {
    background: #372f2b url(../img/search-icon.png) no-repeat center center;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 54px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    width: 20px;
}
.nav > li.nav-search input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #4b4441;
}

/* menu dropdown */
.nav > li > div {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav > li:hover > div {
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: visible;
    visibility: visible;
}

/* menu content styles */
.nav .nav-column {
    float: left;
    padding: 2.5%;
    width: 20%;
}
.nav .nav-column h3 {
    color: #372f2b;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav .nav-column h3.orange {
  color: #ff722b;
}
.nav .nav-column li a {
    color: #888;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 26px;
}
.nav .nav-column li a:hover {
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
    <div>
      <div class="nav-column">
        <h3>Heading 1</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-column">
        <h3>Heading 2</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Heading 3</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>            </div>
      <div class="nav-column">
        <h3>Heading 4</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-column">
        <h3 class="orange">Highlighted Heading</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h3 class="orange">Highlighted Heading</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 5</a></li>
  <li class="nav-search">
    <form action="#">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
      <input type="submit" value="">
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```